# Excel List - Lookup an attendee in a list and return yes / no in the same row

Tags: excel, list, excel-2010, conditional-statements

I have an easy enough question.
I have a list of users that I want to list to number of events.

Example of a list currently:

```
User a - event 1
User b - event 4
User C - event 5
User D - event 2
User b - event 5
User a - event 2
```

In another sheet  have the list of events across the top of the excel
I want to then list each user once and have them attending event a / b / c in the single row.

I'm trying to figure out what Vlookup or if statement i can use to look up if User a is attending event 1 enter 'Yes' etc.

If anyone can help, anything will be a bonus.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you clarify, `I want to then list each user once and have them attending event a / b / c in the single row`.  Also, you need to improve your question by explaining your attempt at resolving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the other sheet, you've got the events across the top (as presumably column headers) - do you have the Users listed down the left, creating a table?